# Read-only check if a git working copy is behind its remote

Tags: git

Is there a git command or combination of commands that tells me if a working copy is behind its remote in a *strictly read-only* way? I'm looking for something that works without errors if the working copy is not writable by the user running the command.

I'm trying to write a cron job that alerts me via e-mail when I need to log in to a certain machine and manually do a git pull to bring the working copy up to date. The cron job's account has read-only permissions to the working copy.

I think this requirement excludes anything involving `git fetch`. It seems that even a `git fetch --dry-run` attempts to write to the working copy:

```
$ git fetch --dry-run
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

This actually lets me achieve what I want since it exits with status 128 when there are changes and with 0 if there are none. However, it doesn't seem completely clean and it could error out for other reasons such as network connectivity issues and I'd like to be able to distinguish between something like that and the out-of-date condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I'd bother to attempt to make this work, but:

You can use `git ls-remote` to grab each remote's idea of the various branch heads (add `--tags` and a specific remote name to get tags as well if desired; you need the specific remote name in this case due to what seems to be a bug in `ls-remote`).  With those, you could then compare the local repository's idea of the remote refs with the ones that came over in the `ls-remote` step, in order to decide whether a full `fetch` is required.

(Using the exit status seems a lot easier though.  As you said, it has some obvious minor drawbacks.)